# Hardcoding headers to excel file using PHP while dynamically querying SQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I have this **PHPExcel** code:

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    //$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
               // ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
               // ->setCellValue('A2', 'world!')

$row = 2; 
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $col = 1;
    foreach($row_data as $key=>$value) {
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
$col++;
    }
        $row++;
    }

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Results');

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Output.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Basically I am dynamically querying the database and placing it into an excel file.

I just want to hardcode in a few headers. So for A1 I'd like to hardcode in "Hello" and A2: "World!" while querying the database and putting the data starting in Column B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('A2', 'world!');

$col = 1; 
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row = 1;
    foreach($row_data as $value) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
        $row++;
    }
    $col++;
}
```

Note that Excel5 has a limit of 256 columns, so if you have more than 255 data records the additional columns will de dropped from the saved workbook if you're saving to that format.

Comment: I am getting a blank page when I run this...Another question I have is- when I run it with that while loop, I am not getting the headers from the database, only the data under. Could you tell me how I can get the headers as well?

Comment: And I only get a blank page when I statically set the A1 and A2. Without that it runs fine

Comment: Does the 01simple.php example from the /Tests directory work?

Comment: yes, they work fine separately but when I try and hardcode headers while dynamically querying the database I get the blank page

Comment: Do you have errors enabled? Are you saving the Excel file to disk or displaying on screen? Can you show more of your code?

Comment: I have edited my code. Everything before that code is the code to link to the database.

Comment: The only thing I can see in your code if the setCellValue() calls are uncommented is a missing semi-colon; but that should throw a PHP error

Comment: Wow, that was it. I never got an error for not having the semi-colon, but it works now. Thanks