# save excel file to a specific folder like my documents PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Below is my code:

```
<?php 
include('../connectdb.php');

$sql = "SELECT
pro.ScholarId, pro.Lastname, pro.Middlename, pro.Firstname, barangays.BarangayName,    levels.LevelName, payroll.Allowance, sca.isClaimed
FROM scholar_profile as pro 
JOIN scholar_school as school ON pro.SchoolId = school.SchoolId
JOIN levels ON pro.LevelId = levels.LevelId
JOIN barangays ON pro.BarangayId = barangays.BarangayId
JOIN payroll ON payroll.PayrollId = levels.PayrollId
JOIN scholar_points as sp ON pro.ScholarPointId = sp.ScholarPointId
JOIN scholar_claim_allowance as sca ON pro.ScholarId = sca.ScholarId 
ORDER BY pro.LevelId, pro.ScholarId";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/** PHPExcel */
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';


// Create new PHPExcel object
#echo date('H:i:s') . " Create new PHPExcel object\n";
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$excel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Payroll");

if(!$result){
die("Error");
}
$col = 0; 
$row = 2; 
while($mrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
$col = 0; 
foreach($mrow as $key=>$value) { 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value); 
    $col++; 
} 
$row++;  
} 

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Scholar Id')
        ->setCellValue('B1', 'Lastname')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'Middlename')
        ->setCellValue('D1', 'Firstname')
        ->setCellValue('E1', 'Barangay')
        ->setCellValue('F1', 'Level')
        ->setCellValue('G1', 'Allowance')
        ->setCellValue('H1', 'Has claimed?');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:H1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(12);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(18);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(18);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(18);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(18);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(12);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(12);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(14);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:H1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridlines(true);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:H1')->applyFromArray(
array(
    'fill' => array(
        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FFFF00')
    )
)
);


// Save Excel 2007 file
#echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to Excel2007 format\n";
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="payroll.xlsx"');
$objWriter->save('payroll.xlsx');

?>
```

**UPDATED MY QUESTION:**
- I have to save it in the my documents folder, so it is easy for user to find it. How to save to it a specific folder?

Comment: Besides the fact that it writes HTML markup, and pretends that it's an Excel .xls file, what's the actual problem? What are the requirements that you have?

Comment: What is that you dont know? I mean where have you been stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck in exporting mysql queries. In my case I have two queries in a table. I don't know how to do it. What I want to do is, when the user would click the Export to Excel, it should do its thing.

Comment: You are dumping **HTML** as **XLS**?

Comment: You are outputting HTML NOT Excel.

Comment: You can't control where the user saves it on their own PC... that's their choice: this isn't a limitation of PHPExcel, it's a restriction of browsers.

Comment: ah so what am I gonna do to let the users save it wherever they want?

Comment: @MarkBaker when I click the export to excel it's not exporting the excel file but the php page. What am I missing here?

Comment: If it's exporting the PHP page, then PHP isn't configured to execute correctly. If it's exporting the Excel file and displaying it as binary characters in the browser, then you're not sending the correct HTTP response headers to tell the browser that the content is an Excel file rather than HTML

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to just export this as a CSV file instead of attempting to export it as the binary XLS format.  Excel can read CSV files just fine, and writing them is probably three orders of magnitude simpler.

If you want to write a CSV file instead, take a look at [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) as a built in PHP function for generating CSV rows.

It's also important to note that the old mysql_* functions are deprecated, and you should look into using at least mysqli but would optimally be using PDO now.

If you **must** export these as true XLS files, there are PHP libraries for doing this that will make your job simpler, but they are not trivial to use and typically have a lot of bugs and gotchas that will take time to work around.

Edit: See the comments for an example of a library for doing this.

Comment: OP Isn't actually trying to export it as the binary XLS , they're trying to export HTML Markup.... and if your suggestion is to export it as CSV, then use fputcsv() rather than your broken "homebrew" writer that forgets to write the commas

Comment: What can you recommend to me a php library which can help for exporting the table from mysql query? thanks. I've read phpcodeplex. but it's so complicated for a beginner like me.

Comment: I'd recommend PHPExcel (assume that's what you mean by phpcodeplex) despite the fact that it may seem complicated (and even though I have a bias as lead developer) because it really isn't as complex as it seems, and there's lots of examples of how to use it

Comment: Can you give me some examples of how to use it please? I need to do finish learning this.

Comment: As a starting example, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166502/hardcoding-headers-to-excel-file-using-php-while-dynamically-querying-sql/13166562#13166562

Comment: thanks. another question, after downloading the phpexcel file, where would I store the folders in it? thanks

Comment: @MarkBaker Good point on the missing comma, but fputcsv is better as a whole.  Truth be told I didn't even know that function existed.  In any case I updated my answer to use it instead because it is indeed less broken than what I wrote.  I still maintain that doing this is going to be much simpler than an external library unless you really need Excel features that CSV doesn't support (seems doubtful the OP does).  :)